# VTK changes for "GetImage" and "Update"

Tags: python, vtk, dicom

I'm trying to get into Extension programming in 3DSlicer using Python.
There is [a tutorial](https://www.slicer.org/w/images/c/c0/Slicer4_ProgrammingTutorial_Slicer4.5.pdf) online. Unfortunately there is a problem with the third example script "HelloSharpen". I did the exact same thing they did but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/HelloPythonSlicer4/helloPython/code/HelloSharpen.py", line 105, in onApply
    laplacian.SetInput(inputVolume.GetImageData())
AttributeError: 'vtkImagingGeneralPython.vtkImageLaplacian' object has no attribute 'SetInput'
```

I solved this by changing `laplacian.SetInput(inputVolume.GetImageData())` to `laplacian.SetInputData(inputVolume.GetImageData())` because I read that they changed this in the newer versions of VTK.

However when I try to run this a new error comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/HelloPythonSlicer4/helloPython/code/HelloSharpen.py", line 107, in onApply
    laplacian.GetOutput().Update()
AttributeError: 'vtkCommonDataModelPython.vtkImageData' object has no attribute 'Update'
```

It seems that `laplacian.GetOutput().Update()` is causing problems so
I tried to find something on the Internet if they also changed this in the newer versions of VTK but I couldn't find anything. I tried to change this into "UpdateData" but this doesn't work.
Do you know if they also changed this and if yes, do you know what I should replace this with?

Here is the full code for "HelloSharpen":

```
from __main__ import vtk, qt, ctk, slicer

#
# HelloSharpen
#

class HelloSharpen:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    parent.title = "Hello Python Part D - Sharpen"
    parent.categories = ["Examples"]
    parent.dependencies = []
    parent.contributors = ["Jean-Christophe Fillion-Robin (Kitware)",
                           "Steve Pieper (Isomics)",
                           "Sonia Pujol (BWH)"] # replace with "Firstname Lastname (Org)"
    parent.helpText = """
    Example of scripted loadable extension for the HelloSharpen tutorial.
    """
    parent.acknowledgementText = """
    This file was originally developed by Jean-Christophe Fillion-Robin, Kitware Inc.,
Steve Pieper, Isomics, Inc., and Sonia Pujol, Brigham and Women's Hospital and was 
partially funded by NIH grant 3P41RR013218-12S1 (NAC) and is part of the National Alliance 
for Medical Image Computing (NA-MIC), funded by the National Institutes of Health through the 
NIH Roadmap for Medical Research, Grant U54 EB005149.""" # replace with organization, grant and thanks.
    self.parent = parent

#
# qHelloPythonWidget
#

class HelloSharpenWidget:
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    if not parent:
      self.parent = slicer.qMRMLWidget()
      self.parent.setLayout(qt.QVBoxLayout())
      self.parent.setMRMLScene(slicer.mrmlScene)
    else:
      self.parent = parent
    self.layout = self.parent.layout()
    if not parent:
      self.setup()
      self.parent.show()

  def setup(self):
    # Collapsible button
    self.laplaceCollapsibleButton = ctk.ctkCollapsibleButton()
    self.laplaceCollapsibleButton.text = "Sharpen Operator"
    self.layout.addWidget(self.laplaceCollapsibleButton)

    # Layout within the laplace collapsible button
    self.laplaceFormLayout = qt.QFormLayout(self.laplaceCollapsibleButton)

    #
    # the volume selectors
    #
    self.inputFrame = qt.QFrame(self.laplaceCollapsibleButton)
    self.inputFrame.setLayout(qt.QHBoxLayout())
    self.laplaceFormLayout.addWidget(self.inputFrame)
    self.inputSelector = qt.QLabel("Input Volume: ", self.inputFrame)
    self.inputFrame.layout().addWidget(self.inputSelector)
    self.inputSelector = slicer.qMRMLNodeComboBox(self.inputFrame)
    self.inputSelector.nodeTypes = ( ("vtkMRMLScalarVolumeNode"), "" )
    self.inputSelector.addEnabled = False
    self.inputSelector.removeEnabled = False
    self.inputSelector.setMRMLScene( slicer.mrmlScene )
    self.inputFrame.layout().addWidget(self.inputSelector)

    self.outputFrame = qt.QFrame(self.laplaceCollapsibleButton)
    self.outputFrame.setLayout(qt.QHBoxLayout())
    self.laplaceFormLayout.addWidget(self.outputFrame)
    self.outputSelector = qt.QLabel("Output Volume: ", self.outputFrame)
    self.outputFrame.layout().addWidget(self.outputSelector)
    self.outputSelector = slicer.qMRMLNodeComboBox(self.outputFrame)
    self.outputSelector.nodeTypes = ( ("vtkMRMLScalarVolumeNode"), "" )
    self.outputSelector.setMRMLScene( slicer.mrmlScene )
    self.outputFrame.layout().addWidget(self.outputSelector)

    self.sharpen = qt.QCheckBox("Sharpen", self.laplaceCollapsibleButton)
    self.sharpen.toolTip = "When checked, subtract laplacian from input volume"
    self.sharpen.checked = True
    self.laplaceFormLayout.addWidget(self.sharpen) 


    # Apply button
    laplaceButton = qt.QPushButton("Apply")
    laplaceButton.toolTip = "Run the Laplace or Sharpen Operator."
    self.laplaceFormLayout.addWidget(laplaceButton)
    laplaceButton.connect('clicked(bool)', self.onApply)

    # Add vertical spacer
    self.layout.addStretch(1)

    # Set local var as instance attribute
    self.laplaceButton = laplaceButton

  def onApply(self):
    inputVolume = self.inputSelector.currentNode()
    outputVolume = self.outputSelector.currentNode()
    if not (inputVolume and outputVolume):
      qt.QMessageBox.critical(
          slicer.util.mainWindow(),
          'Sharpen', 'Input and output volumes are required for Laplacian')
      return
    # run the filter
    laplacian = vtk.vtkImageLaplacian()
    laplacian.SetInputData(inputVolume.GetImageData())
    laplacian.SetDimensionality(3)
    laplacian.GetOutput().Update()
    ijkToRAS = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
    inputVolume.GetIJKToRASMatrix(ijkToRAS)
    outputVolume.SetIJKToRASMatrix(ijkToRAS)
    outputVolume.SetAndObserveImageData(laplacian.GetOutput())

    # optionally subtract laplacian from original image
    if self.sharpen.checked:
      parameters = {}
      parameters['inputVolume1'] = inputVolume.GetID()
      parameters['inputVolume2'] = outputVolume.GetID()
      parameters['outputVolume'] = outputVolume.GetID()
      slicer.cli.run( slicer.modules.subtractscalarvolumes, None, parameters, wait_for_completion=True ) 

    selectionNode = slicer.app.applicationLogic().GetSelectionNode()
    selectionNode.SetReferenceActiveVolumeID(outputVolume.GetID())
    slicer.app.applicationLogic().PropagateVolumeSelection(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Change `laplacian.GetOutput().Update()` to `laplacian.Update()`.

**Explanation:**
As per [this](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput) link, there was a major change introduced in VTK 6. In summary, newer versions of VTK have separated algorithms and the data in two different class hierarchies. In newer versions of VTK, the `Update()` function can be called only on objects which have been derived from the `vtkAlgorithm` class. You can look at the inheritance diagram of `vtkImageLaplacian` [here](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageLaplacian.html) and it is indeed derived from `vtkAlgorithm` class. So `laplacian.Update()` will work.

As the name suggests `vtkImageData` is a data object. `laplacian.GetOutput()` returns a `vtkImageData` object and that's why you cannot call `Update()` function on it and therefore you get the error.